Recive and Send usdt trc20 on laravel
my friends, how can I receive and send usdt in a laravel project on the Tron trc20 platform, of course, I can do this without payment interfaces.
Thank you
I have tried different Laravel libraries, but I don't know the exact and basic solution, of course, I couldn't use these libraries properly because they didn't have complete documentation.
